# Grep list multiple parts of file concatenated with a break

Tags: bash, macos, grep

I've got alias command in my `bash_profile` to list all of my ssh connections in my `~/.ssh/config` file.

My file looks like this

```
Host connection1
Hostname connection1.co.uk
User **user**
IdentityFile /Users/**user**/.ssh/id_rsa

Host connection2
Hostname connection2.co.uk
User **user**
IdentityFile /Users/**user**/.ssh/id_rsa
```

My command simply runs

`cat ~/.ssh/config | grep Host[[:blank:]];`

Which prints out a result like

```
Host connection1
Host connection2
```

How would I change my command so that it prints in the following format (including the breaks)

```
Host connection1
Hostname connection1.co.uk

Host connection2
Hostname connection2.co.uk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also look for empty lines

```
grep -E "^Host|^$" ~/.ssh/config
```

Explanation:

`Option -E`: Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression.
`^Host`:  String Host at the beginning of the line
`^$`: Nothing between beginning and end of the line
`a|b`: matching `a`or matching `b`.

Comment: Explanation added

Comment: Sorry, where is the `a|b` in the answer? Other than that, makes perfect sense, thanks again!

Comment: When you have `"a|b"` it is a or b. So with "^Host|^$" it is `^Host` of `^$`. I tried to avoid confusion, didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk in paragraph mode where it treats each block of text separated by blank lines as a record and then each line within that record as a field. You don't even need to tell it to look for "Host", you can just print the first 2 lines of each "paragraph":

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} {print $1, $2}' file
Host connection1
Hostname connection1.co.uk

Host connection2
Hostname connection2.co.uk
```

Look what else you can do with that as a starting point:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n" }
    {
        delete f
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            tag = val = $i
            sub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",tag)
            sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
            f[tag] = val
        }
    }
    f["Hostname"] == "connection1.co.uk" {
        print f["Host"], f["IdentityFile"]
    }
' file
connection1
/Users/**user**/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The loop creates an array `f[]` which maps the tag names like "Host" to their values and then in the rest of the script you can access the values by their names in `f[]`. So even if your lines were in a different order the rest of the script would still work as you're not relying on the order of the lines, just the names and values set on each line. That makes any other queries or actions you need to perform extremely simple to code and work robustly and portably.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because it's easy to extend to cases where you don't just happen to have a single regex which picks out exactly the lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't search for the blanks,

i.e.

```
grep "^Host" ~/.ssh/config
```

The `^` indicates to start searching from the start of the line. The call to `cat` is useless.

Comment: This also works, but marked the other as correct as this doesn't format it with the blanks (even though you said dont search for blanks), cheers though!